# CM10 Kindle Fire nonresponsive usb storage

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, amazon-kindle-fire

Finally got around to rooting my Kindle Fire, first thing I did was install the latest CM, in my case, CM10. So I played with that for a while and decided to flash to the next ROM, plugged it into my computer, enabled usb storage, began to transfer the new ROM to the /sdcard and as it was doing so, the Kindle unplugged itself (or so the computer thought), and is currently stuck on the 'USB storage in use' screen, and has been for the past hour. Any help?

Comment: Also should mention the ADB doesn't recognize the device.

Comment: NVM, time and a limited battery got the fire to power down, so i could chargeit and turn it on and such. Can we close this thread?

Comment: I am interested in this. I am currently running a version of CM9 that the developer has since abandoned. Where did you get CM10 from, RoyalPain?